# Inequality for parabolic pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I am trying to solve the following exercise.
Consider the linear parabolic equation
\begin{equation}
\partial _t u -\nabla (A(x,t)\nabla u)=f(x,t), x \in \Omega,t>0,
\end{equation}
subject to the initial data $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ for $x\in\Omega$, where the diffusion matrix A satisfies
\begin{equation}
\xi ^{-1}|y|^2\leq \sum _{i,j =1} ^n A_{i,j}(x,t)y_i y_j\leq\xi|y|^2, x\in\Omega,t>0,\forall y \in R^n
\end{equation}
for some $\epsilon>0$.
Let $f\equiv 0$ and consider the Dirichlet boundary condition $u(x,t)=0$for $x\in\partial\Omega$. Show that
\begin{equation}
\lVert u(t)\rVert _{L^2(\Omega)}\leq Ce^{- \lambda t}
\end{equation}
for some $C,\lambda >0$.

I tried the following.

I used the Dirichlet Boundary Condition
\begin{equation}
\int _{\Omega} u\partial _t u dx-\int _{\Omega}A(x,t)\nabla u \nabla u dx=0
\end{equation}
and integrated the first term by parts
\begin{equation}
\int _{\Omega} u\partial _t u dx=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(\int _{\Omega} u^2dx).
\end{equation}
After that I applied the given inequality for A(x,t)
\begin{equation}
\int _{\Omega} A(x,t)\nabla u\nabla u dx \geq\xi ^{-1}\int _{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2 dx.
\end{equation}
By using Youngs inequality I got
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}(\int u^2 dx)+\frac{2}{\xi}\int _{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2 dx \leq 0.
\end{equation}
Then I defined the energy functional
\begin{equation}
E(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int _{\Omega} u^2 dx.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E(t)\leq E(0)e^{-\frac{t}{\xi}}.
\end{equation}
Finally I got
\begin{equation}
\lVert u(t) \rVert _{L^2}=(\int _{\Omega} u^2 dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq (2E(t))^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq Ce^{-\lambda t}
\end{equation}
Is my solution correct or are there any mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing the PDE with $u$ and then using integration by parts yields
$$\int_\Omega u\partial_t u \,dx + \int_\Omega A(x,t)\nabla u\nabla u \, dx = 0.$$
The first integral can be rewritten as
$$ \int_\Omega u\partial_t u \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \int_\Omega u^2 \, dx,$$
while for the second one we use
$$\int_\Omega A(x,t)\nabla u\nabla u \, dx \geq \frac{1}{\xi} \int_\Omega \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \, dx.$$
From there we obtain
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_\Omega u^2 \,dx + \frac{2}{\xi}\int_\Omega\vert\nabla u\vert^2 \, dx \leq 0$$
and you can conclude as above using Gronwall's lemma. 
EDIT: There seems to be another mistake when using Gronwall's lemma. With the above inequality we only have
$$ \frac{d}{dt} E(t) \leq -\frac{2}{\xi} \int_\Omega \Vert \nabla u \Vert^2 \, dx.$$
Here we need to use Poincare's inequality (I suppose $\Omega$ is bounded) to get for some constant $c>0$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} E(t) \leq -\frac{c}{\xi} E(t).$$
Then we can use Gronwall's lemma to conclude
$$ E(t) \leq E(0) e^{-ct/\xi}.$$